# google-sheets api not triggering onEdit function in google sheets

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using php to write data into google sheets. However, the trigger onEdit function on google sheets isn't firing when the data is written from the php.
Here's the piece of code I used to write down the data:

```
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(array('values' => $resultArrayGen));
$params = array('valueInputOption' => $valueInputOption);
$range = 'Main!F2:K';
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $range, $body, $params);
```

Is there anyway to use google services sheets api to trigger the onEdit function in google spreadsheets?

Thanks

Comment: No.Simple triggers only respond to user input. I think the installable onChange can do something like what want check the docs.

Comment: Another possible solution is to use one of the built in sheet triggers and run it every minute to look for changes. The way I do this is use a tracking column. I have one column that the function starts at the end of and looks back to find the last point at which data was entered. Once the code has that row number is starts iterating the new data. At the same time new new data rows are appended with a tracking marker.

Answer (score 2):

The onEdit trigger wont fire according to Google's documentation:

Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For example, calling Range.setValue() to edit a cell does not cause the spreadsheet's onEdit trigger to run.

You can find it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/).

Answer (score 1):

I have found that running the script at set times or in intervals of minutes is the only way to get information regularly if it comes in through another API. For instance, one of the forms I have that comes in does not have a timestamp feature, but allows me to have a hidden field that I can set to put the word Timestamp in the cell I want the date in, so I set my script to run every 5 minutes and to use a text finder. So when it sees the word Timestamp, it replaces it with the time and date of the script run. It's been helpful- not the same as using the Google forms, but we like the form better on the new user portal so we are sticking with it.

I hope that helps!